# Comparing WSDL files

Tags: wsdl

I'm learning all about wsdl files, since I need to transmit data to some places that provide their API's with wsdl.  And I'm on a LAMP environment with SOAP installed.

As I'm reading up on it from http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_ports.asp
I notice the W3 School's version of the  is simpler than the real-life version I'm working with.

Here's W3 School's tutorial version:

```
<message name="newTermValues">
<part name="term" type="xs:string"/>
<part name="value" type="xs:string"/>
</message>
```

And here's a real-life extract from a wsdl file I'm working with:

```
<wsdl:message name="StatesGetXMLHttpPostOut">
<wsdl:part name="Body"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

I notice some differences and some similarities.
Like, why is there "`<wsdl:`" prepended in the latter version?
Is that just some xml flexibility that's understood by SOAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "wsdl"-part is an XML namespace alias. The namespace is required, but there is the concept of a default namespace which applies when no alias is given. This is defined by an attribute on the root element, see for instance [XML Default Namespace](http://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xml_default_namespace.cfm).